# Session access issue in nodejs?

Tags: debugging, node.js, routes

I have modify https://github.com/jimpick/everyauth-example-password/blob/master/server.js for making login with mysql.

I want to access the session in

```
authenticate(function(login, password) {
        var errors = [];
        var user = [];
        userModule.CheckUserLogin(login, password, function(err, results) {
            if(results.length > 0) {
                req.session.login = login;
                return user;
            }
            else {
                if(!user) return ['Login failed'];
            }
        });
        return user;
    })
```

I have this code in bottom

var app = express.createServer(

```
    express.bodyParser()
  , express.static(__dirname + "/public")
  , express.cookieParser()
  , express.session({ secret: 'htuayreve' })
  , everyauth.middleware()
);

app.configure(function() {
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('home', { users: JSON.stringify(usersByLogin, null, 2) });
});
```

If I paste app code from bottom to top then everyayth's routing not worked.I want to simple know how I can access the `req.session.login`  inside everyauth function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the session from your `authenticate` function.  The everyauth way of supporting access the authenticated user's information is for you to provide a `findUserById` function to everyauth that will look up a user record given the user's id that gets stored in the session during authentication.  Once you do that you can access all the user's attributes in your route handlers via `req.user`.

See the 'Accessing the User' section on the [everyauth website](http://everyauth.com/).